# Canada visa refusal, insufficient travel history

Tags: canada, visa-refusals

I applied two times for Canada visitor visa but unfortunately my application has been refused of reason travel history , there are an chance to convince the officer that I will leave Canada in the end of my stay ? There are chance without travel history ?

Comment: They refused because you have no travel history, neglected to provide it, or lied about it?

Comment: There are no chance to convince the officer ?

Comment: Everyone must begin travel at some point and with affluent nations the inexperienced traveller can enter paradox. Just like a new arrival on the job scene, you need one to get one.  If your travel experience is keeping you out of Canada, try to build up an impressive travel history without them.

Comment: Thanks for reply I don't have travel history but i am own company there are an chance to get visa without the reason of travel history

Comment: Of course there is, otherwise people could not begin their travel history.  Somehow people win over the cruel paradox and start to get visas. But for *YOU* it seems Canada is not in the cards as a place to start.  Remember also that first time applicants need a very strong premise, much more so than most.

Comment: Can you tell me what I should do to get the visa pls ?

Comment: @Salamsolo travel elsewhere, to other countries, over a period of several months so as it cant be taken as a deliberate intention to build a false history, and then try again - remember, a visa is not a right, and the country has flagged you up as a high risk traveler (first time traveler, from high risk country etc etc). You need to convince the Canadian immigration people that you are low risk, and the only way to convincingly do that is to be low risk.

Comment: Do you mean travel to some European countries then come back and apply again ?

Comment: We cannot tell you *HOW* to get a visa, there is no recipe or formula.  What we can do is explain the decision-making environment and to speculate on where people go wrong. At the moment, it looks like you need to write Canada off and take a different approach. You can ask a NEW question like "*Somebody told me that first time applicants need to have a very strong premise, what does it mean?*"  The answers you get will NOT help you get a Canadian visa, it's important to be clear about that.  If you really are fixated on Canada, then get a Canadian lawyer to help you. It will cost you dearly.

Comment: You can always improve your travel history by visiting other countries and then you may apply after a few years.

Answer (score 14):

There are several things you can do.

1) The visa refusal letter [doesn't tell the whole story](http://canadianimmigrant.ca/slider/application-refused-what-cic-states-in-refusal-letters-is-not-the-whole-story). What you ideally want to get are the actual case notes from the officer processing your application. These will tell you which areas of your application were strong and which were weak (maybe the problem is more than just travel history). The process to get these notes can be lengthy and complicated, it's described [here](http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/department/atip/requests-atip.asp) (if I'm not mistaken), but you need to be physically present in Canada to make the request, so you'll have to use a Canadian representative, there are some companies that do this [like this one](https://www.gcmsnotes.ca/index.html). But please do your own research, I never actually used this process outside of Canada, nor this company.

2) There is no legal requirement for you to have a history of international travel to be admitted into Canada. If the visa officer saw a problem with your lack of travel history, this probably means that the rest of the application was weak. If there's anything you can do to significantly improve some other section of the application (ties to home country such as family, pre-purchased airline tickets, proof of finances, etc), it can help you.

3) Think about building up an international travel history. Of course, Schengen or USA would be ideal, but from what I've seen and heard anecdotally, almost *any* international travel is much better than no travel at all.

4) Finally, consider getting professional help with your application. A lawyer may be very expensive, but in Canada there are also [Registered Immigration Consultants](http://iccrc-crcic.info/) that may be cheaper.

Sorry to hear you didn't get the visa - the process can be frustrating and lengthy, I wish you luck!

Comment: Thanks for the nice reply dear , only I travelled to turkey three times and nothing more and I am own company and I have ten millions usd on my bank account  , hotel booking and flight tickets will help me to face travel history right ?

Comment: If you truly have at 10 million+ USD in your personal bank account, I'd hire a reputable expert (as in a licensed Canadian immigration lawyer) to assist with your case, as you'd be in a position to afford such personalized advice, despite the cost.

Comment: Great article about not telling the whole story.

Comment: I think only hotel booking and flight tickets would help me

Comment: Heck, with 10MM USD you are eligible for special visas. **Consult a lawyer.** And what flight ticket? With that type of capital I would charter my own plane.

Comment: If you have 10 million usd, then you can simply arrange schengen countries tours, another on (Thailand, Cambodia, Malaysia, Singapore and Indonesia) , also depends on your nationality you could visit (VOA) countries. UK, EU or schengen visas would definitely help in future visa application. As you are already a 10 million dollar man, it wouldn't cost that much.

Comment: If you dont have experience with visas dont try to do it yourself. Consult an expert. If you dont do it right, they will refuse, they dont care if you have millions.