# Canadian tourist visa refused because of travel history and personal assets

Tags: usa, canada, visa-refusals, georgian-citizens

I am from the Republic of Georgia.

I have a visa refusal from the US Embassy and I included this information in my Canadian visa application. In my Canadian refusal letter, only two sections were marked.

The first one was personal assets; at the time, my travel was suponsored by my father. Now,  a lot of things have changed and I have a house, cars and a big company that trades natural methane/ethane gas to different, smaller organizations. I own  50% share of the company.

The second marked section was travel history. I had never been to China, Iran nor any Arabian countries; I had only included refusal information from the US Embassy; this must be the reason for refusal.

This year, I intend to re-apply for a Canadian tourist visa to vacation in August after visiting two European countries.

How do I overcome these refusal problems?

Lately, I have been to Cuba and some Scandinavian countries. I am planning to visit more European countries since Georgian Citizens are no longer required to have a visa to visit Schengen countries.

USA visa refusals (2010, 2012)
Canada visa refusal (2014)

Comment: Provide dates of refusal for both USA and Canada visas

Comment: Please provide a scan of the visa refusal, blacking out any personal information. Vote closing until then.

Comment: @JonathanReez Why vote to close? Canadian refusal notices are very generic unlike UK visa refusals and you will likely not glean anything beyond the information OP provided, namely travel history and personal assets. Closing is premature

Comment: @SheikPaul it is standard policy here on Travel.SE, as it helps dupe-close questions in the future

Comment: @JonathanReez Really, there's no value in seeing the whole Canadian visa refusal notice. The reasons are sufficient. It's just a standard form with specific reasons that may be ticked or not ticked, not too unlike a Schengen refusal - only in the case of Canada the refusal reasons really are not helpful.

Comment: @MichaelHampton the refusal notice is useful for future dupe closing as similar refusal letter usually deserve a similar answer. Otherwise people start arguing that their case is somehow special.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The simple answer is you appear to be doing (or planning to do) all that is necessary to overcome the refusal problems by having acquired personal assets and developing a peripatetic travel history to developed/wealthy countries.

After two USA refusals and one Canadian refusal however, you are starting to tread dangerous grounds and risk spiraling into a refusal vortex.You do not want to give off the perception of being desperate to enter North America.

If you have married and established a family, that will further boost the factors in your favor. Meanwhile make sure your financial documents are very clear and get a well documented trail of your travels via passport stamps etc.

[Canada visa refusal, insufficient travel history](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/77729/canada-visa-refusal-insufficient-travel-history)

Finally since it appears you are a man of some means,  consider getting professional help with your application. A lawyer may be very expensive, but in Canada there are also [Registered Immigration Consultants](http://iccrc-crcic.info/) who may be cheaper.