# What can I send as Travel History in Canada Visa?

Tags: visas, canada

I am applying for the visitor visa to Canada and doing it online.
The info button says:

> You must provide information on your valid visa from the United States
> as well as previous travel history. This can include copies of
>
> - your previous passports and/or visas (used within the last 10 years to
>   travel outside your country)
> - entry and exit stamps
> - study and/or work permits that indicate your duration outside of your country
> - expired or valid visas
> - boarding passes
>
> If you hold a valid visa from the United
> States, provide a clear, scanned copy of your visa. If you are living
> outside your country of citizenship, please submit a copy of your
> immigration status document for the country where you currently
> reside.  This could be a work permit, study permit, visa, or any other
> document that authorizes you to be in the country where you are
> living.

I never travelled to USA or Canada, have no stamps on my passport yet, no international boarding pass used before and never studied or worked internationally.

It is a required document, so I am not sure what to do.

Comment: what visa are you applying for and where do you see this text? I can only presume you have accidentally clicked into a visa category for people in transit through Canada to the US or something

Comment: @nkjt visitor visa, on application forms there is "Application for Visitor Visa", so I think it is right, this one I am speaking about in the post is in Supporting Documents section

Answer (score 1):

It is not a requirement to have a travel history, what the info says there is that *if* you have those *then* you must attach them. As this [answer](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/77736/4188) also notes

> There is no legal requirement for you to have a history of international travel to be admitted into Canada.

Finding a source for a negative would be quite hard. However, anecdotally, this [forum post](https://www.canadavisa.com/canada-immigration-discussion-board/threads/visitors-visa-got-denied-due-to-travel-history.572106/#post-7088791) concurs:

> My brother[...] never traveled before. But he got visa for 10 years